# Will be HashMap capacity increased if I permanently storing objects in a single bucket?

Tags: java, hashmap

HashMap has:

> When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of
> the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is rehashed
> (that is, internal data structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table
> has approximately twice the number of buckets.

So will it be capacity increased if I permanently storing objects in a single bucket ( make `hashcode()` always `return 0`)?

Comment: What possible reason can you have for subverting the whole point of a hash map by forcing `hashCode()` to return zero for all (or multiple non-`equals()`) instances?

Comment: I exaggerate `hashCode()` to let people focus at the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will still resize (see the [source code of HashMap.putVal()](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l624)):

```
final V putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent,
               boolean evict) {
    // [code left out ...]

    ++modCount;
    if (++size > threshold)
        resize();
    afterNodeInsertion(evict);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, when amount of entries in HashMap (not buckets) becomes to be more than capacity * loadFactor, then amount of buckets will be increased twice, so HashMap will be rehashed and entries will be dustributed among new buckets.

Comment: In case of `hashcode()` always `return 0` they stay in place